# git pull error "The requested URL returned error: 503 while accessing"

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I've been facing problems accessing my git repository lately.  It worked perfectly fine earlier but now I cannot run any command on CLI. I can however, access the corresponding Web Page, Could someone help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you accessing it via http/https or thourgh SSH? is the repository on the internet or your local network? if on internet, check your proxy settings on the shell.

Comment: Your question is too vague to me. Can you add more detail?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I can clone repositories I made a few months ago just fine. I can clone repositories that I have access to. But the repository I just created 2 days ago - I cannot clone it.    I have tried this both on my local machine, and on a remote server that I have access to. I see exactly the same problem. donb@gcc20:~$ git clone https://github.com/donbright/truetype_to_svg.git
Cloning into truetype_to_svg...
error: The requested URL returned error: 503 while accessing https://github.com/donbright/truetype_to_svg.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
git 1.7.2.5

Comment: update: i just 'waited a while' and retried - and it worked.

Answer (score 65):

Had the same error while using **SourceTree** connected to **BitBucket** repository.

When navigating to repository url on [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org) the warning message appeared:

> This repository is in read-only mode. You caught us doing some quick maintenance.

After around 2 hours repository was accessible again.

You can check status and uptime of bitbucket here:
http://status.bitbucket.org/

Comment: Same issue today: `We're doing some maintenance. We'll be right back.`  Thanks

Comment: If I navigate to bitbucket, it says `Performing Backup: backup is currently underway and shouldn't take too long`

Comment: Also, source tree is a flaming pile of garbage. You should use git command line :)

Comment: I quit the sourcetree and opened it again. Then tried pushing, works.

Answer (score 26):

here you can see the latest updated status form their website

[bitbucket site status](http://status.bitbucket.org/)

if     `Git via HTTPS`   status is  `Major Outage`, you will not be able to pull/push, let this status to get green

> HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable

Answer (score 22):

Try disabling all the system wide HTTP and HTTPS proxies:

```
export http_proxy="" 
export https_proxy=""
export HTTP_PROXY=""
export HTTPS_PROXY=""
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense if the OP in question actually needs the proxy to access internet. (Also, doesn't git take it's proxy from the .git/config file? )

Comment: I realized I was connected through a VPN, disconnecting worked.

Comment: This solved my problem. I had set a proxy in environment variables which prevented me to access the intern bitbucket instance.

Comment: @ffledgling env variables are apparently higher priority than at least the credential manager, so if they are set git will try using them instead

Comment: I was having the OP's error with our organization level git server while using TortoiseGit. I was able to successfully do a `git pull` in a Dos box command line which has the system environment vars `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` removed.

Answer (score 15):

Its problem at bitbucket's end.

You can check status of their services at http://status.bitbucket.org/

Currently there is `HTTPS` outage at bitbucket.  see below

[image]

You can use `SSH` option. I just used `SSH` option with `sourcetree`.

Answer (score 8):

As in "[CocoaPods - pod setup http request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355595/6309)", a 503 error on accessing (cloning) a *public* repository is likely to be the result of a GitHub glitch (availability issue)

Retrying later usually works.

Answer (score 7):

A 50X error is an **internal server** error. There's nothing wrong on your end, but something's up on the server's end.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle
>   the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the
>   server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which
>   will be alleviated after some delay.

Just be patient and wait. :-)

Comment: No! As Evgeniy said it was a proxy problem for me

Comment: It could be a problem caused from the server end due to configs done in the client end. i.e proxy settings

Answer (score 2):

Every one please avoid modifying post buffer and advising it to others. It may help in some cases but it breaks others. If you have modified your post buffer for pushing your large project. Undo it using following command. 
`git config --global --unset http.postBuffer` 
`git config --local --unset http.postBuffer`

I modified my post buffer to fix one of the issues I had with git but it was the reason for my future problems with git.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error when trying to clone a heroku git repository.

Upon accessing heroku dashboard I saw a warning that the tool was under maintenance, and should come back in a few hours.

```
Cloning into 'foo-repository'...
remote: !        Heroku has temporarily disabled this feature, please try again shortly. See https://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/foo-repository.git/': The requested URL returned error: 503
```

If you receive the same error, check the service status

Comment: I've considered  useful to add this response related to heroku here, than to create another topic for a subject so similar

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not only created by `no_proxy`, because it created by `git server down` issue also.

So When happening this issue first you open and check gitlab in browser.

And check if It shows any error like `"503 An internal server error occured".` .

The gitlab shows `"503"` page, this issue create by gitlab server down not in your system.

So you wait some time until the server going up and continue your work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today. Apparently, **Google Compute Engine** was down today for 2-3 hours (GitLab uses it). By that time, I had to use a VPN inorder to pull the update from the repo. I didn't want to wait.

```
pranav@exam ~/j/just-perfection-gnome-shell-desktop (master)  git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/justperfection.channel/just-perfection-gnome-shell-desktop.git/': The requested URL returned error: 503
git: 'gitlab-rake' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
pranav@exam ~/j/just-perfection-gnome-shell-desktop (master) [1]> nordvpn connect us
Connecting to United States #8244 (us8244.nordvpn.com)
You are connected to United States #8244 (us8244.nordvpn.com)!
pranav@exam ~/j/just-perfection-gnome-shell-desktop (master)> git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 149, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (149/149), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (99/99), done.
remote: Total 118 (delta 88), reused 23 (delta 15), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (118/118), 710.93 KiB | 289.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (88/88), completed with 19 local objects.
From https://gitlab.com/justperfection.channel/just-perfection-gnome-shell-desktop
   3008d67..5cf51ac  master     -> origin/master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

So my suggestion for you is either wait for it to come back online or try using VPN and see if it works. This is a server-side problem as mentioned by experts above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using git from gitlab on Linux when running

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:MYPROJECT
```

on a fresh linux install, output:

```
The requested URL returned error: 503
```

I simply had to create an ssh key pair (probably the error will also disappear when the you use password authentication for https URLs instead, this answer only shows the key pair approach).

Choose from:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 
ssh-keygen -t dsa 
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

Just press enter to save it to the standard directory, decide whether you want an additional passphrase. Then copy the content of the public key

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

to the ssh key on gitlab, here in the case of rsa as the encryption method.
Add the private key to your ssh.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Try clonging:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:MYPROJECT --branch MYBRANCH
```

It should ask to check a fingerprint to be checked against https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/, to be sure, you may check this, and then the clone command works.

Answer (score -13):

The solution:

> error : The requested URL returned error : 503 while Accessing

The error might be resolved by deleting the existing git folder.