# CocoaPods - pod setup http request failed

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

Working on OSX 10.8.2

After a fresh install of CocoaPods.
I'm trying to

```
$ pod setup
```

And I get

```
[!] git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master

Cloning into 'master'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 503 while accessing
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a glitch, due to some Github availability issue:

From [Github status page](https://status.github.com/messages):

> Today (January 16th, 9:50 UTC)
>
> We are working to resolve issues with a couple of fileserver clusters. Only a small number of users will be affected.

From

> Upstream network connectivity issues continue to affect GitHub access for a small percentage of users.
> We've received notification that one of our upstream network providers will be performing emergency maintenance on malfunctioning device to attempt to resolve this later today.

So if you retry later, it should work.

Since it is a public repo, an address like https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git can work for read (pull for everyone) and write (collaborators only).

Comment: I am always the small number of users experiencing the temporary issues :) Thanks, it works now