# git push to GitLab is failing with HTTP 503 error

Tags: git, gitlab

I setup a new project in GitLab and followed instruction given in GitLab to setup repo in my laptop. But, I am getting `error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503 ServicUnavailable`

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/{my_username}/{prject_name}.git
cd {prject_name}

touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"

git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 227 bytes | 227.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503 Servic                                                                                            e Unavailable
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: HTTP 50x errors are server errors, meaning there's nothing wrong on your end. Wait, try again later.

Comment: try these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066100/git-pull-error-the-requested-url-returned-error-503-while-accessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have cloned read-only. I'm not sure about Gitlab, but often it is not possible to push to a repo cloned via https.

I suggest cloning with ssh.

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:{username}/{project_name}.git
```